# "Call from" qc 35 Bose ubuntu 18.04 even though no call

Tags: bluetooth

I have connected my Bose qc35 to Ubuntu 18.04 and they worked fine until an update recently. My issue is that when I watch media files I will get a "call from" the voice inside the headphones even though no calls incoming.

I have no idea why this happens. They worked fine before 16 Septembers update.

Any one have an idea why this happens?

Here are my **logs** with search "bluetooth"

14:51:14 bluetoothd: Unable to get io data for Phone Book Access: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)

14:51:14 obexd: disconnected: Transport got disconnected

14:51:14 bluetoothd: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)

14:50:38 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257

14:49:37 obexd: stat(/home/boggie/phonebook/): No such file or directory (2)

14:49:35 bluetoothd: connect error: Device or resource busy (16)

14:49:19 obexd: disconnected: Transport got disconnected

14:47:37 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257

14:47:32 obexd: stat(/home/boggie/phonebook/): No such file or directory (2)

14:47:31 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0

14:47:17 bluetoothd: connect error: Device or resource busy (16)

14:09:09 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0

13:41:11 bluetoothd: Unable to get io data for Phone Book Access: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)

13:40:49 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0

13:40:39 bluetoothd: Unable to get io data for Phone Book Access: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)

13:40:36 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0

12:23:12 bluetoothd: Unable to get io data for Phone Book Access: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)

12:22:53 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257

Answer (score 2):

This was solved by changing the profile in the settings for bluetooth. The problems occur when the profile is HSP/HFP. You should use A2DP Sink

Comment: Note that the A2DP profile prevents you from using the microphone in your headphones (you'll use the one in your computer instead). So this workaround has (possibly unwanted) side effects.